# JQuery selectors don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the following input on my page:

```
<input type="text" name="r1" />
```

I am trying to select it with JQuery, using `$("[name='r1']")`, and for some reason it returns `null`. Ok, fine, the title is misleading in that it is me that is doing something wrong; can you tell me what?

**EDIT:**

`$('input[name="r1"]')` doesn't work either. Also, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Are you referencing it after the element is rendered?

Comment: the name in your example is "r1" not "r2" is that at typo here or is there an "r2" in your code you are trying to select?

Comment: - check working demo on fiddle by clicking link in my answer ...its working properly...

Comment: If the selectors don't seem to work it's probably because your are attempting to find them before the page has actually (fully) loaded. Make sure your jQuery code to find elements is running after the document has loaded $(document).ready(function() {... }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Last EDIT

### [Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hkLES/)

Html Code

```
<input type="text" name="r1" />​
```

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert($('input[name="r1"]').length);
});​
```

---

**OLD Updates**

you have typo error here you are trying to find `r2` element which is not there just update code like `$("[name='r1']")`

or

to find it proper way you should do as below

`$("input[name='r2']")` instead of `$("[name='r2']")` only

**EDIT**

According to you edited question you should check example over here : [**Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

**EDIT**

for proper check you can do like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert($('input[name="r1"]').length);
});
```

Comment: Be careful of the space between `input` and `[name='r2']`. It will trigger a descendant selector, i.e. it will match elements whose `name` attributes are `r2` and which are descendants of `<input>` elements, not the `<input>` elements themselves as `input[name='r2']` would do.

Comment: @Bluefire - check working demo on fiddle by clicking link in my answer ...its working properly...

Answer (score 2):

Just made a quick test:

```
<input type="text" name="r1" />​
```

with the following Javascript

```
$('input[name=r1]').click(function(e){
  alert('found');
});​
```

It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You are not telling jQuery what element you're looking for, that is you `input`

Try doing it this way

`$('input[name=r1]')`

Comment: `input` is not required, unless there are more than one element with the `name` attribute of `r1/r2`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the selector is wrong. Should be `r1` as opposed to `r2`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/r4LdA/)

```
$("[name=r1]")
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to include the html tag for attribute filters.

```
$("input[name='r2']");
```

Please refer to [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) link for further information on attribute selectors.

Answer (score 1):

It will work definetly:

```
$("*[name='r1']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `$("[name='r1']")` and `$('input[name="r1"]')` in this scenario

Use `$("[name='r1']")` if you want to select any element with attribute called "**name**" equal to "**r1**"

Use `$('input[name="r1"]')` if you want to select only **input** elements with attribute called "**name**" equal to "**r1**"

More JQuery Attribute fillter examples are listed [here](http://jascripts.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-to-use-jquery-attribute-filters.html)